# How to use a shared object repository across projects in UFT?

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I have two projects in UFT and one of the projects have a few functions and object repository that I want to use in second project.
Is there a way to do so without copying the content?

Answer (score 0):

UFT has [Shared object repositories](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2022/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Object_Repositories.htm) in which you can put common objects and [function libraries](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2022/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Assoc_Lib_Files_TD.htm) in which you can put shared functionality.

Comment: But does that allow to share these resources across multiple projects?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "projects" it allows you to share these resources between different tests, different users and different machines. As long as UFT can access the resources it can use them in a test.

Comment: Ok. What I know so far is if you have an object repository and function library of your own, you can not use it outside the project in which you have created it. Using it in same project is easy. You can add as many as tests in a project and share the OR and Function Library among them as long as all sit in same project.